# one hot encoding returns all 0 vector for last categorical value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, one-hot-encoding

`tf.one_hot()` is yielding `[0,0,0]` vector for the third class of possible categorical values.

I would expect a `[1,0,0]`. What am I doing wrong with this function?

There are 3 possible categorical classes that I want to One-Hot encode. 1,2,3 using `tf.one_hot()`.

Example:

```
# 3 possible classes
print(df['sent_score'].unique())
# array([1., 2., 3.])


#original
labels1 = np.asarray(df['sent_score'])
print("Original Labels \n", labels1[25:30])

# Original Labels 
# [2. 1. 2. 1. 3.]   

 
# one hot encoded
labels = tf.one_hot(labels1, 3)
print("\nOne Hot labels \n", labels[25:30])

# One Hot labels 
#    [[0. 0. 1.]
#    [0. 1. 0.]
#    [0. 0. 1.]
#    [0. 1. 0.]
#    [0. 0. 0.]]  ##WHY IS THIS VECTOR is [0,0,0] and not [1,0,0]
```

Comment: @DavidS my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `tf.one_hot` also consider `0` as a class, so given that your labels are 1-3, when passed to `tf.one_hot` it just filled the `3` class with `0`s.

Simple example:

```
indices = [0, 1, 2]
tf.one_hot(indices, 3)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>

indices = [0, 1, 2, 3]
tf.one_hot(indices, 3)
# array([[1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 1.],
#        [0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

So you should change the classes to be in the range of 0-2 and then pass them to the `tf.one_hot`

[Refernece](https://www.programmersought.com/article/47112119837/)